# SSH_FX_PERMISSION_DENIED when using ssh package Golang, but copying with filezilla is working

Tags: go, ssh, remote-server, filezilla

I am trying to copy a file from local to server with the help of SSH package and Golang. When I try to copy am getting **sftp: "Permission denied" (SSH_FX_PERMISSION_DENIED)** error.

here is the sample code

```
clientConfig := &ssh.ClientConfig{
    User: "username",
    Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
        ssh.Password("password")
    },
}
// connet to ssh
addr = fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", host, port)

if sshClient, err = ssh.Dial("tcp", addr, clientConfig); err != nil 
{
    return nil, err
}

// create sftp client
if sftpClient, err = sftp.NewClient(sshClient); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
// create destination file
dstFile, err := sftpClient.Create("/folderpath/filename")
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("error creating destination %v ", err)
}

defer dstFile.Close()
srcFile,err := os.Open("localFilePath")

// defer io.Copy(dstFile, srcFile)
bytes_copied, err := io.Copy(dstFile, srcFile)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

But I can copy the file through Filezilla with the same credential. I have drwx--- permission for folders and -rw--- permission for files.

Let me know what will be the issue, what I missed?

Comment: What specific line of code is producing the error?

Comment: I am getting error on 
bytes_copied, err := io.Copy(dstFile, srcFile)

this line